# Why does a string in PHP not contain an empty string?

Tags: php, string, stripos

Consider the following piece of code which somehow returns `false`:

```
<?php var_dump(stripos("foo", "")); ?>
```

It returns `bool(false)`, not `int(0)` on PHP 7.4.

I thought every string contained the empty string.

So what is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: "Note that the needle may be a string of one or more characters.".

Comment: This function returns the zero-based string offset where the needle can be found in the haystack. If empty strings were always a match, what offset should be returned? There's no way to extract an empty string from a PHP string using a offset.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I thought 0.

Comment: In this example, `0` would also be `f`. An option could have been `-1`, but `$somestring[-1]` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

> Returns `false` if the needle was not found.

The purpose of this is possibility to strictly compare result with `false` in order to find out that `needle` is not found in `haystack`.

```php
if (stripos("foo", "") === false) {
    // Here we definitely know "" is not contained in "foo"
}
```

Comment: I thought `stripos("foo", "")` meant if `""` was contained in `"foo"`, not the other way around.

Comment: Confused them, fixed, thanks.